# Pattern History Table of 2-bit Saturating Counters

Tags: c, branch, counter, prediction

The problem I am currently working on is to write a gshare simulator that takes in branch instruction addresses and taken/untaken instructions for a 2-bit saturating counter.  Meaning, my input looks something like this:

0ffd7a78 1

The 2-bit saturating counter program I wrote correctly calculates the number of mispredicts as well as the misprediction rate.  I understand the logic behind a 2-bit saturating counter.  However, I am having trouble wrapping my head around the concept of the gshare simulator, which in my case uses a BHSR (Branch History Shift Register) that consists of a variable bit index XORed with that number of bits that come from the least significant bits of the instruction address.  The BHSR, by my understanding, contains the last n number of occurences and is used to index into a Pattern History Table.  Each entry in the Pattern History Table contains its own 2-bit saturating counter that is used to give a prediction.  I have been working on/thinking about this for hours and perhaps I am just overthinking it.  How can I implement my 2-bit saturating counter to make a table of multiple 2-bit saturating counters to populate a Pattern History Table?  This is my first time asking a question on here so I hope I am following the correct format.  My code for the 2-bit saturating counter program is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define RECORDS 4000000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int bitIndex = atoi(argv[1]);       //The argument entered by the user, defines bit index
int numEntries;         //Number of entries as determined by bit index
numEntries = pow(2, bitIndex);
int bht[numEntries];            //Integer array that holds the Branch History Table
int count;              //Used to clear out the Branch History Table

//Loop through the entire Branch History Table and make sure all cells are set to 0.
for(count = 0; count < numEntries; count++){
    bht[count] = 0;
}

int i;                  //Set up our counter
int mispredict = 0;         //Tells the number of mispredicts
int predict = 0;            //Tells the number of correct predictions

//Branch Prediction Record
char hexAddress[8];         //Address in branch prediction record stored as a string
int direction;              //The 0 or 1 will tell us whether to go up or down in a state change

for(i = 0; i < RECORDS; i++){
    scanf("%s %d", hexAddress, &direction);
    //printf("The address is %s\nThe direction is %d\n", hexAddress, direction);

    //BEGIN NUMBER CONVERSION

    //LOOKING FOR LEAST SIGNIFICANT BITS (bitIndex)
    //CONVERT HEX ADDRESS TO BINARY

    char originalHexAddress[8];
    strcpy(originalHexAddress, hexAddress); //Preserve the original address
    int j;                  //Counter for this internal loop
    char binaryString[32] = {""};       //Sets up a "string" for the binary conversion

    //Loop through the hex address and turn each component into its binary counterpart
    for(j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            if(hexAddress[j] == '0'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "0000");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "0000");
                }
        }                   
                if(hexAddress[j] == '1'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "0001");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "0001");
                }
        }
        if(hexAddress[j] == '2'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "0010");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "0010");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == '3'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "0011");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "0011");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == '4'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "0100");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "0100");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == '5'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "0101");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "0101");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == '6'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "0110");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "0110");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == '7'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "0111");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "0111");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == '8'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "1000");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "1000");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == '9'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "1001");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "1001");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == 'A'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "1010");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "1010");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == 'B'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "1011");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "1011");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == 'C'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "1100");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "1100");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == 'D'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "1101");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "1101");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == 'E'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "1110");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "1110");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == 'F'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "1111");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "1111");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == 'a'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "1010");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "1010");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == 'b'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "1011");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "1011");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == 'c'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "1100");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "1100");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == 'd'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "1101");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "1101");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == 'e'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "1110");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "1110");
                }
        }
                if(hexAddress[j] == 'f'){
                if(binaryString[0] == '\0'){
                    strcpy(binaryString, "1111");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(binaryString, "1111");
                }
        }
        }
    //printf("The binary string representation of %s is:\n%s\n", originalHexAddress, binaryString);

    //Now we must convert the appropriate binary component into it's decimal representation
    //CONVERT FROM BINARY TO DECIMAL

    //First, must get to the end based on our bit index
    int decimal = 0;
    int stringpos;

    //Loop starts at the appropriate value in the binary string and converts it to a decimal using bit shifting
    for(stringpos = (32 - bitIndex); stringpos < strlen(binaryString); stringpos++){
            decimal = decimal << 1;  
            if(binaryString[stringpos] == '1'){
            decimal += 1;
        }

    }
    //printf("The decimal value based off your bit index is %d\n", decimal);

    //END NUMBER CONVERSION

    //BEGIN WORK IN BHT

    /*
    LOGIC NOTE
    If the state is 0 or 1, predict NOT TAKEN
    If the state is 2 or 3, predict TAKEN
    If prediction is correct, then note it.
    If prediction is not correct, mark it as MISPREDICT.
    */

    //2-BIT SATURATING COUNTER

    //Based off our bit index, we will go to a specific cell in the table for each address
    //bht[decimal] represents which state we are currently in - 0, 1, 2, or 3
    //while(direction){
        switch (direction){
            //Lower state until saturate at 0
            case 0:
                //If state is 0 or 1, CORRECT PREDICTION, state will become 0
                if((bht[decimal] == 0) || (bht[decimal] == 1)){
                    bht[decimal] = 0;   //Keep or move to state 0
                    predict++;      //CORRECT PREDICTION
                    //printf("Stayed in state 0.\n");
                }
                //If state is 2, MISPREDICT, lower to state 1
                else if((bht[decimal] == 2)){
                    bht[decimal] = 1;   //Move to state 1
                    mispredict++;       //MISPREDICT
                    //printf("Lowered to state %d\n", state);
                }
                //If state is 3, MISPREDICT, lower to state 2
                else if((bht[decimal] == 3)){
                    bht[decimal] = 2;   //Move to state 2
                    mispredict++;       //MISPREDICT
                }
                break;

            //Increase state until saturate at 3
            case 1:
                //If state is 0, MISPREDICT, increase to state 1
                if((bht[decimal] == 0)){
                    bht[decimal] = 1;   //Move to state 1
                    mispredict++;       //MISPREDICT
                    //printf("Stayed in state 3.\n");
                }
                //If state is 1, MISPREDICT, increase to state 2
                else if((bht[decimal] == 1)){
                    bht[decimal] = 2;   //Move to state 2
                    mispredict++;       //MISPREDICT
                    //printf("Increased to state %d\n", state);
                }
                //If state is 2 or 3, CORRECT PREDICTION, state will become 3
                else if((bht[decimal] == 2) || (bht[decimal] == 3)){
                    bht[decimal] = 3;   //Keep or move to state 3
                    predict++;      //CORRECT PREDICTION
                }
                break;
        }

    //}
    //printf("Number of entries: %d\nPredicts: %d\nMispredicts: %d\n", numEntries, predict, mispredict);    
    //printf("The state is %d\n", bht[decimal]);
}
//Calculate rate
double rate;
rate = (((double)mispredict / 4000000) * 100);
printf("%d entries (%d-bit index): mispredicts = %d, rate = %.2lf%%\n", numEntries, bitIndex, mispredict, rate);



return 0;
}
```

NOTE:  I know I could have simplified the conversion to binary and saved a lot of space, but at the time I wrote that code I was just looking for a way to make it work, which does.  I haven't felt the need to go back and try to modify it, so excuse the length.